# Making connections with python3 asyncio

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, python-multithreading, python-asyncio

I'm trying to connect to more than one server at the same time. I am currently using `loop.create_connection` but it freezes up at the first non-responding server.

```
gsock = loop.create_connection(lambda: opensock(sid), server, port)
transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(gsock)
```

I tried threading this but it created problems with the sid value being used as well as various errors such as `RuntimeError: Event loop is running` and `RuntimeError: Event loop stopped before Future completed`.  Also, according my variables (tho were getting mixed up) the protocol's `connection_made()` method gets executed when `transport, protocol = loop.run_until_complete(gsock)` throws an exception.

I don't understand much about the asyncio module so please be as thorough as possible.  I dont think I need reader/writer variables, as the reading should be done automatically and trigger `data_received()` method.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You can connect to many servers at the same time by scheduling all the coroutines concurrently, rather than using `loop.run_until_complete` to make each connection individually. One way to do that is to use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to schedule them all and wait for each to finish:

```
import asyncio

# define opensock somewhere

@asyncio.coroutine
def connect_serv(server, port):
    try:
        transport, protocol = yield from loop.create_connection(lambda: opensock(sid), server, port)
    except Exception:
        print("Connection to {}:{} failed".format(server, port))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(
    asyncio.gather(
      connect_serv('1.2.3.4', 3333),
      connect_serv('2.3.4.5', 5555),
      connect_serv('google.com', 80),
 ))
loop.run_forever()
```

This will kick off all three coroutines listed in the call to `gather` concurrently, so that if one of them hangs, the others won't be affected; they'll be able to carry on with their work while the other connection hangs. Then, if all of them complete, `loop.run_forever()` gets executed, which will allow you program to continue running until you stop the loop or kill the program.

The `reader`/`writer` variables you mentioned would only be relevant if you used [`asyncio.open_connection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio.open_connection) to connect to the servers, rather than `create_connection`. It uses the Stream API, which is a higher-level API than the protocol/transport-based API that `create_connection` uses. It's really up to you to decide which you prefer to use. There are [examples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol) of [both](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-stream.html#asyncio-tcp-echo-client-streams) in the `asyncio` docs, if you want to see a comparison.

Comment: Im still wondering if its okay to use run_until_complete() while run_forever() is going.  I guess I'll try that after I rewrite.

Comment: Actually this is not a working solution because the sockets are not fully active (unless all the server connections succeed in a timely manner).  The program hangs waiting for one of the connections to a server.

Comment: @baudsmoke I'm not sure what you mean. What sockets aren't fully active? What specifically is hanging? The program is designed to block in the `run_until_complete` call, possibly forever if one of the calls to `connect_serv` never returns. However, the `connect_serv` calls that don't hang should continue to work just fine.